# Category Theory: homset preserves limits

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, representable-functor

**edit** I updated my question at the end, I think the claim may be false?

---

> Let $(L,\lambda)$ be a limit cone of a diagram $D$ in a category.
>
> For any object $X$ it is said that the hom functor $Hom(X,-)$
>   preserves limits.

How can I prove $(Hom(X,L),\lambda \circ -)$ is a limit cone in Set?

Because Set has all limits, I tried to build the limit there and got a universal map from it to that cone, but I need to show that map is an isomorphism to say its the limit cone.

I think this might not work at all, **what is a nice way to prove it?**

---

I got further with a simple example, products and found this:

> - $Hom(X,A\times B) \to Hom(X,A)\times Hom(X,B)$ by universal map
> - $Hom(X,A)\times Hom(X,B) \to Hom(X,A\times B)$ let $(f,g) \in Hom(X,A)\times Hom(X,B)$ then $x \mapsto (fx,gx) \in Hom(X,A\times B)$
>     and the legs of the cones commute because $f = x \mapsto f x$.
>
> The composition of both maps $Hom(X,A)\times Hom(X,B) \to
> > Hom(X,A)\times Hom(X,B)$ is the identity because every self map from a
>   limit that makes legs commute is the identity.

**But how do I show the composition is the identity other way around? 
Is $Hom(X,A\times B) \to Hom(X,A\times B)$ true?**

Hopefully this will generalize too.

---

Thanks to Hurkyl,

> If $T$ is a terminal object, then $Hom(X,T)$ is a one element set so
>   it's a terminal object in Set.

Using this idea I also proved the claim for equalizers in the category of finite sets.

> If E is the equalizer of finite sets A and B, then $Fin(X,E)$ has
>   $|E|^{|X|}$ elements. If F is the equalizer of $Fin(X,A) \to \to
> > Fin(X,B)$, but all the $Fin(X,B)$ maps factor through $A$ so that $|F| =
> > |E|^{|X|}$, then the sets are isomorphic.

---

Proving it for equalizers would give the theorem for all finite limits by the fact a finite limit can be constructed from these three primitives, but I would like to know:

**Is there a uniform proof for an arbitrary diagram?**

Comment: Are you asking questions one-by-one from an exercise sheet or something? I'll give you a hint anyway: show that the limit of $\textrm{Hom}(X, D)$ is precisely the set of cones from $X$ to $D$.

Comment: I'm just trying to close the gaps in my understanding. I don't understand your hint because the limit is a single cone not a set of cones.

Comment: this question is because "representable functors preserve limits since they are isomorphic to homset functors, which preserve limits".. but I didn't have proof of that.

Comment: I found a proof here but don't understand it http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2007/06/22/preservation-of-limits/

Comment: I'm really stuck on this and I posted my ideas so far please help. it's not homework.

Comment: If $T$ is terminal, then $\hom(X,T)$ is a set with one element.

Comment: Yes, there is a uniform proof for all diagrams. It is the proof that you linked to.

Comment: I know but I don't understand that proof.

Comment: "Assume (S,f) is a cone [for universal map] in Set, show that for each s, [X,f_i(s)] is a cone" is the key to discover this proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

page 9 of http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Henderson.pdf

Let $D : \mathcal J \to \mathcal C$ be a diagram for some locally small category $\mathcal C$.

Let $(L,\forall i \in \mathcal J, L \overset{\lambda_i}{\to} D(i))$ be a limit cone of that diagram.

Let $X$ be any object of $\mathcal C$.

Let $(S,\forall i \in \mathcal J, S \overset{f_i}{\to} \mathcal C(X,D(i)))$ be any cone over the diagram $\mathcal C(X,D-) : \mathcal J \to \mathbf{Set}$.

We want to construct a unique map $u : S \to \mathcal C(X,L)$ that makes the legs commute.

Given $s \in S$, we have a cone $(X,\forall i \in \mathcal J, X \overset{f_i(s)}{\to} D(i))$ in $\mathcal C$ and thus a universal map $u_s : X \to L$ such that $f_i(s) = \lambda_i \circ u_s$ for each leg, and the triangles of the cone commute because $f_i(s)$ came from a cone.

This gives us a map in set $u : S \to \mathcal C(X,L)$ that makes all the legs of the cone commute. It is also the unique such map because it is pointwise unique.

That proves the theorem.

Answer (score 7):

There is a rather silk proof which requires some observations:

1. Let $F$ be a diagram in $\mathcal{C}$ indexed by $\mathscr{J}$. Then, a *limiting cone* $(\lim F, \mu\colon \Delta \lim F \to F)$ corresponds exactly to an isomorphism
   $$
     \mathcal{C}(X, \lim F) \cong [\mathscr{J}, \mathcal{C}](\Delta X, F).
   $$
   natural in $X$ where the right hand side is just the set of cones over $F$.
2. The set of $F$-cones with tip $B$ is isomorphic to $[\mathcal{J}, \mathbf{Set}](\Delta 1, \mathcal{C}(B, F-))$.
3. When $\mathcal{C} = \mathbf{Set}$ and $X = 1$ in the first isomorphism, we have 
   $$
     \lim F \cong [\mathcal{J}, \mathbf{Set}](\Delta 1, F)
   $$
   i.e. the set of cones from a singleton set $1$ over $F$ *is* the limit of $F$.

Finally, we arrive the conclusion that the set $\mathcal{C}(B, \lim F)$ is the limit of $\mathcal{C}(B, -) \circ F$ from
$$
\mathcal{C}(B, \lim F)
\cong [\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{C}](\Delta B, F)
\cong [\mathcal{J}, \mathbf{Set}](\Delta 1, \mathcal{C}(B, F-))
\cong \lim \mathcal{C}(B, F-)
$$
where the first isomorphism follows from our first observation, the second from the second observation, and the third from the inverse of the third observation.